# Can't figure out how to save different R Objects with varying names

Tags: r

When working with multiple objects I like to use the same naming scheme and refer to the objects using eval and parse. For example when I want to work with the mean of Objects A and B, I have variables named A.mean, B.mean and use them in functions like this:

```
system <- c("A", "B")

eval(parse(text = paste(system[1], ".mean", sep = "")
```

This usually works great except with the save {base} function. When I write something like:

```
    for (i in i:2){
    save(eval(parse(text = paste(system[i], ".mean", sep = ""))), 
    file = paste("Mean_", system[i], ".RData", sep = ""))
    }
```

R returns:

```
Error in save(eval(parse(text = paste(system, ".mean", sep = ""))),  : 
  object ‘eval(parse(text = paste(system, ".mean", sep = "")))’ not found
```

Anyone got an idea how to use save with a variable like this?

Comment: Can you use `get(paste0(system[1],".mean"))` instead of `eval(parse(...))`?

Comment: If you need to use the `eval(parse())` paradigm, you are probably doing something off. Have you tried using lists and their corresponding functions like `lapply` and `sapply`?

Comment: No gives me the same Error

Comment: if `get(...)` gives you the same error, *then the object does not exist* (where you think it does). Please include the output from `ls()`.

Comment: @roman
I have very big lists from different calculations saved as .RData files. I write my functions so that I only need to input a string of names and R loads the corresponding file, does another calculation and then saves the new value using the same name + an identifier. For this I use eval(parse()) because my files are too big to put them all in the same list and it's more convenient to just input the affromentioned string of names. A.mean doesn’t appear in my global environment, so I need eval(parse()) to pass the variable to a function using lapply and sapply.

Comment: If `A.mean` doesn't appear in your global env, how will `eval(parse(...))` find it?

Comment: @r2evans
get(paste0(system[1],".mean")) and eval(parse(text = paste(system[i], ".mean", sep = ""))) both return the same object A.mean
I can pass an object this way to every function except save.

Comment: typing ls() returns:`[1] "A.mean" "B.mean" "system"` Typing `eval(parse(text = paste(system[1], ".mean", sep = "")))` returns the value for A.mean.
Typing `save(eval(parse(text = paste(system[1], ".mean", sep = ""))), file = paste("Mean_", system, ".RData", sep = ""))` returns the affromentioned error.

Comment: `save(list=paste0(system[i], ".mean"), file=paste("Mean_", system[i], ".RData"))`. You're missing the fact that `save` uses nonstandard evaluation to determine the ***name*** of the object you are trying to save, so `eval(parse(...))` is not surprisingly not a legal name. (The object is stored with this name in the rdata file.) By providing `list=...`, you are telling it the names to use, and it will go and fetch them. Your use of `eval(parse(...))` is really unnecessary.

Comment: Okay thank you that works. Usually passing the name of an object as a character to the function doesn't work and I have to use `eval(parse(...))` so my first thought was it would be the same for `save`.